# Subsets of a set containing an empty set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

First of all, is **A** ={φ} a set?
If yes, then what are its **subsets**?

Note:
• φ represents an empty set.

• **A** must have two distinct subsets,
      (∵ n(**A**)=1, thus 2¹= 2)

My approach:
According to me, if it has two subsets then they should be φ and φ. If it's so then they aren't distinct at all.

Comment: The usual symbol foe *empty set* is $\emptyset$ (\emptyset). Having said that, yes : $A = \{ \emptyset \}$ is a set with exactly one element: the *empty* set.

Comment: And yes; every finite set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subsets. Thus, having $A$ one element, the number of its subsets is $2$. **Every** set $A$ has $\emptyset$ and $A$ itself between its subsets; thus...

Comment: In conclusion, $A = \{ \emptyset \}$ has **two** subsets: $\emptyset$ and $\{ \emptyset \}$. The two are different: the first one is empty while the second one has one element.

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\{\emptyset\} \ne \emptyset.$

$$\mathcal{P} ( \{\emptyset\} )=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \}.$$

$$\mathcal{P} ( \emptyset )=\{\emptyset\}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 1):

- In virtue of the definition of " subset"

> in order a set $X$ to be  a subset of $\{\emptyset\}$ it is necessary ***and sufficient*** that all the elements of set $X$ be also
>   elements of $\{\emptyset\}$.

- Your question therefore amounts to :

> which set(s) can I substitute for $X$ in the sentence " all the
>   elements of set $X$ are also elements of $\{\emptyset\}$ " in order to
>   make a true sentence?

- Setting $X = \emptyset$ results in a true sentence.

Note : since $\emptyset$ has no element, one can truly say that all its elements belong to any arbitrary set S  ; otherwise, it would mean that some element of $\emptyset$ does not belong to S, which is absurd.

- Setting $X = \{\emptyset\}$ also results in a true sentence.

For, certainly,  $\{\emptyset\}$ has no element that does not belong to $\{\emptyset\}$ itself.

- No other substitution would result in a true sentence.

In fact I already have 2 subsets, and , as you pointed out, since the cardinal of your original set is $1$, the cardnal of its power set ( that is, the number of its subsets) is $2^1 =2$.

- So $P(\{\emptyset\}) = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for a deep insight

Comment: If ever you please, you may give a +1. But your thanks are already a great reward to me:)

Comment: Thanks for this +1:)

Comment: Pardon me, your answer deserved one but I forgot to hit that +1 button.

Comment: No prob, that's ok:)